# exchange words in echo

Tags: php

with this code

```
$wptitle = str_replace(array('Versandkostenfrei'), 'Kostenloser Versand', $wptitle);
```

I exchange words in one of my loops.

Now I am trying to change a word that is called with `echo $term->name;` how do I implement that? I tried

```
<?php 
$wptitle = str_replace(array(' .echo ($term->name;)'), '', $wptitle); 
?>
```

but its obviously not working :-(

Comment: What is `.echo ($term->name;)` in an array?

Comment: Can you show the part where `echo $term->name;` occurs? (couple of lines before and after so we have context)

Comment: I am using ´<?php echo $term->name; ?>´  to show a Word in a custom taxonomy/theme

Comment: You'll probably want something like `$wptitle = str_replace($term->name, 'neuer Text', $wptitle);` (also, this isn't a wordpress question. this is a PHP question)

Comment: thanks working, sorry using it in my Wordpress theme, but you are right its php sorry und thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP [`echo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) language construct that outputs the parameters passed. You don't want to do that in the middle of [`str_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). To replace $term->name with an empty string, use:

```
$wptitle = str_replace( $term->name, '', $wptitle );
```

Then when you want to print it, use:

```
echo $wptitle;
```